# Error processing request: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'xxx'@'xxx' (using password: YES)

Tags: magento

There has been an error processing your request

SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'celebrit_celebri'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Coming in magento when i m opening my web ..

How to sove it ..?

Answer (score 0):

Check your database if your USER exist, and if is a password correct.

You can change configuration of magento DB user, DB name, and password in magentofolder/app/etc/local.xml

Answer (score 0):

please check your app>etc>`local.xml`

in `local.xml` db name and password written please check with uour db connection details

it may solve your problem